# Using Selenium, Find List Item and Click On It

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on a unordered list element for the element id = search_explorer, but can figure out how to find the drop down list item so I can click on it. Here is the elements and what I have tried. ele returns null. Can someone please help me?

```
<ul class="menu menu_header dropit">
            <li class="dropit-trigger menu_tools_item dropit-open"> <a href="#">KEYWORD</a>
                <ul style="width: 175px;" class="dropit-submenu">
                    <li class="menu menu_header menu_header_item dropit menu_tools_item" id="keyword_explorer" domain="0"><a class="menu_tools_item_a" href="#">Keyword Explorer</a></li>
                    <li class="menu menu_header menu_header_item dropit menu_tools_item" id="search_explorer" domain="0"><a class="menu_tools_item_a" href="#">Search Explorer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
 </ul>

ele = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".menu.menu_header.menu_header_item.dropit.menu_tools_item")).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == "Search Explorer");
ele.Click();
```

Comment: By.XPATH("//li[@class='menu menu_header menu_header_item dropit menu_tools_item']/a[.='Search Explorer']") try using the following.

Comment: I get NoSuchElement for this...

ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='menu menu_header menu_header_item dropit menu_tools_item']/a[.='Search Explorer']"));

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to click on drop down element to open the list and click on the specific element. Use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `ElementToBeClickable`()

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector(".menu.menu_header.dropit")));

new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("#search_explorer >a")));
```

Comment: new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector(".menu.menu_header.menu_header_item.dropit.menu_tools_item"))); cause WebDriverTimoutException. I also get the same exception for new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector(".menu.menu_header.dropit")));

Answer (score 0):

----**Update**---

Based on the updated information from the comments:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

// Use Actions to simulate mouse movement
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

// Move to the first element to hover 
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".dropit-trigger")));

// Wait for search_explorer element to be visible    
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("search_explorer")));

// Assign the search_explorer element to a variable
var searchExplorer = driver.FindElement(By.Id("search_explorer"));

// Move to the search_explorer element now that it's visible
action.MoveToElement(searchExplorer);

// call Actions.Perform() to execute the actions in the browser
action.Perform();

// Now click search_explorer element
searchExplorer.Click();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried all 3 methods you suggested above and non work. The only thing I know is that when I move my mouse over the top menu item KEYWORD, the sub menu items display and when the mouse is moved to "Search Explorer" and left click the sub menu item, the next panel displays. I'm totally stumped/

Comment: That helps. Check out this blog post: http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automating-hoverable-multilevel-dropdowns/  ‘MoveToElement’ simulates the mouse hovering and can be used to chain the events together like the ones you’ve explained above. I will try to write the code in the morning